# How To Remove Ugly Header Material From Bioinfo Class?

Tags: pdftex, templates

I am trying to write a report using the `bioinformatics` class, a template for which has been provided here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-oxford-bioinformatics-journal-new-version/zjrmbrmtrytg

If you look at the template PDF on the Overleaf page, you see that it prints a whole bunch of info at the top of the page e.g.

> "main"-2017/4/20-3:38-page 1-#1

I think this is really ugly and would like to remove it. However, I cannot find the part of the style file that actually produces it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do not use the template if you don't like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `bioinfo` loads package `crop` and puts crop marks on the page and page information in the header. The page information is in the top edge that will be cut off.

To remove the information from header add class option `noinfo`:

```latex
\documentclass[noinfo]{bioinfo}
```

[image]